# show the author's role along with the name in the single.php

Tags: user-roles, author

some way to show the author's role in wordpress for example: Administrator, editor, author, contributor ect...

Let something like this be left:

This post was written by ***contributor*** JUan

I'm just using `<? php the_author (); ?>` but I can't think of anything else to show the role of the user assigned to a post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get author role in single.php you have to get author id first. Use following code to get author id

```
$author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
```

Then get userdata using

```
$user = get_user_by( 'ID', $author_id);
```

or you can use

```
$user = get_userdata( $author_id );
```

now you can display role of author using :

```
echo implode(', ', $user_info->roles);
```